# HTACCESS Rewrite rules

Tags: .htaccess

I need help to redirect the following URL (in htaccess)

```
http:www.domain.com/article/the-bp-oil-spill-one-year-later/19918396/20110420/
```

To

```
http:www.domain.com/article/the-bp-oil-spill-one-year-later/19918396/2011/04/20/
```

my original rewrite is:

```
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([0-999999999]+)/([0-99999999]+)/?$ /index.php?a=show-post&slug=$1&articleid=$2&date=$3 [QSA,L]
```

and I am trying to do away with this to a pattern which is like:

```
 domain/2011/04/20/article-name-here/
```

Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks,
L

Comment: What do you mean by "rewrite" exactly? What is the incoming, what is the target URL? Do you have rewriting already in place?

Comment: Sorry, my fault. I've edited the post to clear myself.

Comment: So the target URL is a physical file? If it isn't - please show what rewriting you already have for that

Comment: Edited the original to add my code.

Comment: @LShetty it would be best if you edited it into your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you after something like this:

```
URL Example: blah/20080101/

RewriteRule ^blah/([0-9]{0,4})([0-9]{0,2})([0-9]{0,2})/$ /blah/$1/$2/$3/
```

Would output:

```
/blah/2008/01/01/
```

Answer (score 0):

Current/Old: /article/the-bp-oil-spill-one-year-later/19918396/20110420/

```
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([0-999999999]+)/([0-99999999]+)/?$ /index.php?a=show-post&slug=$1&articleid=$2&date=$3 [QSA,L]
```

Desired/New: 2011/04/20/article-name-here/

```
RewriteRule ^article/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]{0,4})([0-9]{0,2})([0-9]{0,2})/?$ /$3/$4/$5/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

This will allow existing links to your current/old style urls to be redirected (permanently) to your new style urls. This assumes that your php app doesn't *need* to also have the articleid passed to it - note that articleid is not in your new/desired URL.